# Prove that $|\frac{\tilde{f}(x+h) -\tilde{f}(x) }{h} - f^\prime(x)| \leq \frac{2 \varepsilon}{h} + \frac{Lh}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Given that:
$f^\prime(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous, with Lipschitz constant L and $|\tilde{f}(x) -f(x)| \leq \varepsilon $ 
I am supposed to prove that :
$|\frac{\tilde{f}(x+h) -\tilde{f}(x) }{h} - f^\prime(x)| \leq \frac{2 \varepsilon}{h} + \frac{Lh}{2},
h > 0$ 
My proof so far: 
$\tilde{f}(x+h) = f(x+h) + E_1$, $ E_1 \in \mathbb{R}, |E_1| \leq \varepsilon$ 
$\tilde{f}(x) = f(x) + E_2$, $ E_2 \in \mathbb{R}, |E_2| \leq \varepsilon$ 
$|\frac{\tilde{f}(x+h) -\tilde{f}(x) }{h} - f^\prime(x)| = 
 |\frac{ f(x+h) + E_1 - (f(x) + E_2) }{h} - f^\prime(x)| \leq |\frac{E_1}{h}| + |\frac{E_2}{h}|+
 |\frac{ f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f^\prime(x)| \leq \frac{2 \varepsilon }{h} + |\frac{ f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f^\prime(x)|$ 
 $
 = \frac{2 \varepsilon }{h} + |f^\prime(\xi) - f^\prime(x)|$ (with $\xi \in (x, x+h)$)
$\leq  \frac{2 \varepsilon }{h} + L|\xi-x| \leq \frac{2 \varepsilon }{h} + Lh$ 
But I am really not sure where the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from...
So I was hoping someone could help me out (or confirm my suspicion that the original task is wrong)

Comment: You can use: $f(x+ h) \leq f(x) + f'(x) h + \frac{1}{2} Lh^2$ which follows from the Lipschitz continuity of $f'$.

Comment: Does this also work when $f^\prime$ is not differentiable? . As this just looks to me like a Taylor expansion using the fact that $f^{(2)}(x)$ is bounded by L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\int_0^1 hf'(x+sh)\,ds=hf'(x)+h\int_0^1(f'(x+sh)-f'(x))\,ds$$
so that indeed
$$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-f'(x)\right|\le\int_0^1L|(x+sh)-x|\,ds=\frac{Lh}{2}.$$